# Issue in Return type declarations of a static function - PHP 7.0.0

Tags: php, static-methods, php-7, return-type

I'm facing the issue in Return type declarations of static function in **`PHP 7.0.0`** version.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Kindly look at the following code

```
Following code is working: Non-Static Function

<?php

$object = new MyClass();
$object->SetName('StackOverflow');
echo($object->GetName());

class MyClass {
    private $Name;

    public function SetName($name) {
        $this->Name = $name;
    }

    public function GetName($name) : string {
        return $this->Name;
    }
}

?>
```

Following code not working: Static Function

```
<?php

$object = new MyClass();
$object->SetName('StackOverflow');
echo(MyString::Trim($object->GetName()));

class MyClass {
    private $Name;

    public function SetName($name) {
        $this->Name = $name;
    }

    public function GetName($name) : string {
        return $this->Name;
    }
}

class MyString {
    public static function Trim($str) : string {
        return trim($str);
    }
}

?>
```

> ***Parse error:*** syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   /home2/ramesh/public_html/test.php on line 20

Issues only arising in `static function` not in ordinary `function`. Kindly assist me how to achieve this.

Comment: What is `public class MyString` mean to express? What is a "public class"?

Comment: Works fine for me if you remove the `$name` parameter from the `GetName()` method and fix that "public class" glitch...

Comment: Since you get an other, unrelated error (according to what you posted) we have to assume that the above is not the actual code you tried.

Comment: sorry, its a typo mistake, I removed in my question. Kindly wait.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me if you remove the `$name` parameter from the `GetName()` method and fix that "public class" glitch:

```
<?php

$object = new MyClass();
$object->SetName('  StackOverflow  ');
var_dump(MyString::Trim($object->GetName()));

class MyClass {
    private $Name;

    public function SetName($name) {
        $this->Name = $name;
    }

    public function GetName() : string {
        return $this->Name;
    }
}

class MyString {
    public static function Trim($str) : string {
        return trim($str);
    }
}
```

This obviously creates that output:

```
string(13) "StackOverflow"
```